# Programmatically setting a unique object ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I have the following code

```
<div id='show_test'></div>
```

And

```
var matches = [{
    "category_name": "category_1",
    "stock_name": "stock_1",
    "supplier_stock": "supplier_stock_1"
}, {
    "category_name": "category_2",
    "stock_name": "stock_2",
    "supplier_stock": "supplier_stock_2"
}, {
    "category_name": "category_3",
    "stock_name": "stock_3",
    "supplier_stock": "supplier_stock_3"
}, {
    "category_name": "category_4",
    "stock_name": "stock_4",
    "supplier_stock": "supplier_stock_4"
}];
matches.forEach(function(i, item) {
    var arrayDt = [];
    arrayDt[i, item] = {
        "category_name": this.category_name,
        "stock_name": this.stock_name,
        "supplier_stock": this.supplier_stock
    };
    document.getElementById("show_test").innerHTML += "<div><a id='bt_" + item + "'>click</a></div>";

    document.getElementById("bt_" + item).onclick = function() {
        show_data(i);
    }

    console.log(document.getElementById("bt_" + item));
    console.log(i);

});

function show_data(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

On the page we show 4 links, when I click on the last link, the script functions as expected. But not the first 3. Why does this not work with the first 3 links?

https://jsfiddle.net/a35wL5ht/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For this to be a useful question, you’ll need to make it more broadly applicable to questions that other people also ask: check out the guidelines on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show what other resources you’ve used, and what you’re hoping to do with this. We’re a community rather than a coding service!

Comment: Improved formatting, question clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
document.getElementById("show_test").innerHTML += '<div><a href="#" id="bt_' + item + '">click</a></div>';
```

with

```
var el = document.createElement("div");
var a =  document.createElement("a");
a.innerHTML = "click";
a.id = "bt_" + item;
el.appendChild(a);
document.getElementById("show_test").appendChild(el);
```